# ShadowRoot not finding elements inside template repeat in Polymer

Tags: dart, polymer

I'm having trouble with accessing the shadowDom of a Polymer element. Here is the (truncated) code for the element:

```dart
<polymer-element name="word-element" attributes="chars">
  <template>
    <h2>Drag and drop the letters to form anagrams</h2>
    <div id='container'>
      <div class="char" draggable="true">a</div>
      <div class="char" draggable="true">b</div>
      <div class="char" draggable="true">c</div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <template repeat="{{chars}}">
        <div class="char" draggable="true">{{}}</div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Here is what the Dart code looks like:

```dart
@CustomTag("word-element")
class WordElement extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {
  @observable List chars;

inserted() {
    var charDivs = this.shadowRoot.queryAll('.char');
    print(charDivs.length);
}
```

`charDivs.length` always returns 3, counting the 3 `<div>`s that I have hard coded into the `<template>`. Any divs created within the `<template repeat="{{chars}}">` code is not discovered by using `shadowRoot`.  Any ideas why this may be the case?

Also, when I apply styles to elements with the class `char`, the styles are applied to *all* `<div>`s, including the ones created inside the `repeat`. But using `shadowRoot` only returns the hard-coded divs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Mutation Observers for this. As mentioned elsewhere, the template bindings and repeats happen asynchronously, sometime after the custom element is created and inserted.

Use a Mutation Observer to be notified when a node or its subtree is modified.

Here's the Dart code:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

@CustomTag("my-element")
class MyElement extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin {
  final List<String> timestamps = toObservable([]);
  MutationObserver observer;

  created() {
    super.created();

    observer = new MutationObserver(_onMutation);
    observer.observe(shadowRoot.query('#timestamps'), childList: true, subtree: true);

    new Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (t) {
      timestamps.add(new DateTime.now().toString());
    });
  }

  // Bindings, like repeat, happen asynchronously. To be notified
  // when the shadow root's tree is modified, use a MutationObserver.

  _onMutation(List<MutationRecord> mutations, MutationObserver observer) {
    print('${mutations.length} mutations occurred, the first to ${mutations[0].target}');
  }
}
```

Here's the HTML code:

```html
<polymer-element name="my-element">
  <template>
    <ul id="timestamps">
      <template repeat="{{ts in timestamps}}">
        <li>{{ts}}</li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="my_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the query into a `Timer.run`.

```
Timer.run(() {
  print("timer");
  var charDivs = this.shadowRoot.queryAll('.char');
  print("charsDiv: ${charDivs.length}");
});
```

Then, when I populate the `chars="{{someList}}"` attribute with a list, eg: `['d','e','f']`, I get the full set (ie, `length=6`) returned.

Here's a gist demonstrating the complete code: https://gist.github.com/chrisbu/6488370

Comment: Do we have guarantee that the bindings will all be complete by the next event loop?

Comment: That's a fair question, and I like your answer better.

Comment: Chris, I accepted Seth's answer, but your's works too. The only problem I have is that using a `Timer()` is not a guarantee, although it is likely to work most of the time.

Comment: Yes, I'm happy with that caveat, too.